# External class folder not exportable?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

Eclipse, Android project. I have a library project (mylib) and an app that references it (myapp). I've added to the build path of mylib a folder with a bunch of compiled Java classes (com.foo.*), checked it as exported. Added a call to one of those classes to the main activity. There are no build errors. But when I run myapp and try to call a method from com.foo, I get a "class not found" exception.

When I package the same class folder into a jar file and reference/export that in Eclipse, the app works.

What am I doing wrong? Are class folders not subject to export somehow?

EDIT: here's my thinking. The Java Build Path window treats JAR's and class folders uniformly. Any why shouldn't it - a JAR is, for the most part, just a class folder zipped up. But then there's this discrepancy of behavior when passing classes on to other projects. Unexpected...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it an android library and import it as such in the android panel

Comment: if you want to refer to a java project (that is, not as a jar) from an Android app, you need to do as i wrote. That allows you to access the resources as well. That's the usual may of including an android project into another. (because you often have resources with your project)

Comment: I have two Android Java projects, and an external project that's not for Android and not even in Java, it just compiles to JVM classes (and has no resources, obviously). I can link to and use the latter when it's packaged as a JAR, but cannot when it's not.